# Fill List box with result from stored procedure C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, stored-procedures

I have search a bunch for this and as you can tell I'm very new to C#, I I'm trying to learn this language.

So please forgive me if one of the 100 forms that I have looked at says the same thing that you post here.

I am trying to populate a list box with a the results from a stored procedure called `LookupInvoices`, this requires a parameter `@InvoiceNumber` that is an `int`.

I have a WPF that I would like to populate a listbox called `lstResults` with the results from this stored procedure.

Please look at my code and tell me where I have made an error, thanks so much for your time!

```
private void btnFill_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbInvoiceNumbers.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please Choose A Invoice Number!");
        return;
    }

    SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JAMES-DESKTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=contacts;Integrated Security=True");

    int cboItemNumber = cmbInvoiceNumbers.SelectedIndex;
    int invNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cmbInvoiceNumbers.Items[cboItemNumber].ToString());

    cs.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LookupInvoices", cs);

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        SqlParameter pram = new SqlParameter("@invoiceNumber", invNumber);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pram);
        cmd.Connection = cs;

        reader.Read();
    }

    cs.Close();
}
```

Please not that when I click the button it crashes. This doesn't run all the way through.

Comment: Do you get an exception? What does the output say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your all disposable elements (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader`) into `using (....) { ...... }` blocks, and you need to add the parameter ***before*** calling `.ExecuteReader()` - try this code:

```
public class InvoiceDto
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public void List<InvoiceDto> GetInvoiceData(int invoiceNumber)
{
    List<InvoiceDto> data = new List<InvoiceData>();

    using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JAMES-DESKTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=contacts;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.LookupInvoices", cs))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@invoiceNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = invoiceNumber;

        cs.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                InvoiceDto dto = new InvoiceDto();
                dto.Description = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(0);
                dto.Hours = reader.GetFieldValue<int>(1);
                dto.Amount = reader.GetFieldValue<decimal>(2);

                data.Add(dto);
            }
        }

        cs.Close();
    }

    return data;
}
```

and in your code-behind, you should call this method in your event handler

```
private void btnFill_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // get selected invoice number
     int cboItemNumber = cmbInvoiceNumbers.SelectedIndex;
     int invNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cmbInvoiceNumbers.Items[cboItemNumber].ToString());

     // call method to get the data from the stored procedure
     List<InvoiceDto> data = GetInvoiceData(invNumber);

     // loop over the data and fill your listbox
     foreach(InvoiceDto dto in data)
     {
         listbox.Items.Add(dto.Description);
     }
}
```

Comment: And all of that db-code should be at least in a separate class and preferably [in a separate layer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AReminderOnThreeMultiTierLayerArchitectureDesignBroughtToYouByMyLateNightFrustrations.aspx).

Comment: And put your connection string in the config instead of hard coded in the app.

Comment: can you please explain why this worked? also can you help me populate the listbox with the results?

Comment: @user3120232: hard to help - I have **no idea** what that stored procedure returns, and what you want to use as your listbox items ....

Comment: ok, my apologies; it will return a table of items that were sold on that invoice, 3 columns description nvarchar(125),hours int, and amount money.

Comment: I had to *guess* what order these items are returned in - you might need to tweak the lines inside the data reader loop. Also, I didn't know what you want to add to your listbox - again, that's just an *example* - adapt it as needed! But important part is: try to **separate** your data retrieval **out of the button click handler** - don't mix UI code (button click handler) and database related code too tightly !

Comment: thank you, I plan on this populating once I change the combo box. thank you again for your time.

Comment: @user3120232: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.